# Slim Partial with Yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a Slim partial for a widget.  The widget has common elements and then some custom content that I want to yield to.  What's the correct syntax for that?  Here's what I thought would work, but doesn't.

Widget Partial

```
.container
  .title= title
  .content
    == yield
```

Page

```
.page
  = render partial: "widget_partial", locals: { title: "Content 1" } do
    div Some really awesome content.

  = render partial: "widget_partial", locals: { title: "Content 2" } do
    span Different but also awesome content.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Action View Overview](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#partials) on partials (section 3.2.3), when you are only using a partial template and locals, you can get away with a minimal approach like this:

(widget partial)

```
.container
  .title
    p #{title}
  = yield
```

(Page)

```
  = render "widget_partial", title: "content 1" do
    .div
      p Some really awesome content.

  = render "widget_partial", title: "content 2" do
    .div
      p Different but also awesome content.
```

Note that in the partial, itself, you cannot put text directly into a 
`div`, so I added a `<p>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `layout` argument in the `render`. Something like this:

(widget partial)

```
.container
  .title = title
  .content
    = yield
```

(page)

```
.page
  = render layout: 'widget_partial', locals: { title: 'Content 1' } do
    div Some really awesome content.

  = render layout: 'widget_partial', locals: { title: 'Content 2' } do
    span Different but also awesome content.
```

Doc: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#partial-layouts